# Como fazer para que os arquivos sejam puxados da raiz do site?

Tags: php

Estou criando um site... Até aí tudo bem.

Criei URL's amigáveis.

Antes minha URL era algo como:

```
localhost/site/produto.php
```

E agora é:

```
localhost/site/produtos/produto/planos
```

Queria um código `PHP` que puxasse todos os links da raiz do site.

> Ex: Antes meu site puxava uma imagem com o nome `imagem.png` no caso `imagens/imagem.png`, mais depois de mudar minha URL, agora tenho que utilizar `../../imagens/imagem.png` porque se não fizer isso nas imagens por exemplo, vai dar todos **erro 404**.

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que ele mude o url do diretório automaticamente sem que eu tenha que editar de um por um?

No caso seria:

```
    href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/imagens/imagem.png"
```

Agora vem o problema: Como colocar o código acima `<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>` automaticamente em todas as imagens via `PHP`?

Comment: Raiz do site você se refere ao diretório inicial do Apache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode setar de duas formas

1º - utilizando "/" antes dos links. Ex.:

```
<img src="/images/uploads/upload-10-50-100.png" alt="" />
```

2º - Criar um subdominio com seus scripts, imagens e css. Ex.:

```
<img src="http://assets.seusite.com.br/images/upload-10-50-100.png" alt="" />
```

Há mais opções e com certeza uma ferramenta para tal, mas de qualquer forma, utilize a primeira opção caso não queira apontar para um subdominio.

Answer (score 6):

Uma forma legal é ter uma constante definida tendo o caminho da raiz do site. Por exemplo:

```
define("SITE", "http://menusite.com.br/");
```

Ai nas imagens ficariam assim:

```
<img src="<?= SITE ?>imagens/minhaimagem.png" alt="" />
```

O legal desta abordagem é que irá funcionar perfeitamente no localhost também, pois você pode definir a constante para o diretório que quiser, por exemplo, `http://localhost/meusite/`. Quanto a editar uma por uma suas referências no código não tem como fugir, mas qualquer IDE tem uma funcionalidade para executar um replace geral no projeto.

Comment: MUITO LEGAL!!!!!